# Nginx reverse dns with cloudflare

Tags: nginx, reverse-dns, cloudflare, verification

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/rdns/

https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns

How do you get the nginx-http-rdns module to work with cloudflare free DDoS protection? I wish to use this module to verify search engine bots (issue #10 has ways to verify bots). But it is unknown how to make this module work with cloudflare DDoS (issue #19 - has a stackoverflow example). Can anyone help? Or maybe there is a way to do it without this module?

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445810/nginx-http-rdns-with-cloudflare

Comment: What is your current configuration? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Please add details to the question with edit -feature.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I currently do not have a configuration. I plan on using this but I want to see how it is done normally. I noticed in other places across the web though that other users have been having problems so we could start by troubleshooting with that.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [realip module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) to substitute the client's IP address for CloudFlare's addresses. This happens in the first [phase](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases) of processing, before anything else is done. The RDNS module would then work normally and see the client's IP address rather than CloudFlare's.

An example configuration (the [IP ranges](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/) might be out of date; I need to check on that):

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the answer. That makes a lot of sense. Is there any other configuration needed on the nginx-http-rdns side?

Comment: @masuking You would configure the rdns module to whatever your particular needs are.